# Is there a way to override busday_count method in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to override np.busday_count to include custom off days. How do I do it?

Comment: Is there a reason why either the `weekmask` or the `holidays` argument of that method won't do what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [`holidays`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.busday_count.html) parameter of `np.busday_count`:

```
np.busday_count('2021-01', '2021-02', holidays=['2021-01-05'])
```